# System mem can't add up afer open huge pages

Tags: linux, memory

Platform: two Oracle Linux7.5 servers and they have an Oracle RAC database.

Database version:12.2.0.1

Huge pages: enable.

**problem description:**

After I enable the huge pages function, I found that used mem + free mem + buff/cache + available mem **much more than** total mem in these two servers.

Below are some mem data of one node.

As I know, huge page mem is unusable for other applications once the system allocates it even the system has mem pressure. So this part of mem can not be the available mem.

After I **turn off the huge page function**, the figures for free -g command seems normal.

**Question: Why my server has so much available mem(35.66GB, total mem is 64GB) despite it used 55G? How Linux calculate all these figures?**

MEM DATA-----huge page function enable

[*@*~]$ free -tm <<-----node-2

```
   total       used        free     shared    buff/cache   available
```

Mem:   63819       55146        1471      944       7201       36515

Swap:  65531          15       65516

Total: 129351       55162       66988

### File Name or Source

file name =node2_meminfo_19.11.06.1100.dat

zzz ***Wed Nov 6 11:00:02 CST 2019

MemTotal: 65351524 kB <<<<<<62GB in total

MemFree: 2137568 kB <<<<<<2GB free

MemAvailable: 38189832 kB

Buffers: 13832 kB

Cached: 4424852 kB

SwapCached: 0 kB

Active: 38255876 kB

Inactive: 1384672 kB

Active(anon): 4706984 kB

Inactive(anon): 94764 kB

Active(file): 33548892 kB <<<<<<32GB memory in OS filesystem cache

Inactive(file): 1289908 kB

Unevictable: 401128 kB

Mlocked: 401128 kB

SwapTotal: 67104764 kB

SwapFree: 67104764 kB

Dirty: 560 kB

Writeback: 0 kB

AnonPages: 4254508 kB

Mapped: 675800 kB

Shmem: 808328 kB

Slab: 1735924 kB

SReclaimable: 1612152 kB

SUnreclaim: 123772 kB

KernelStack: 18736 kB

PageTables: 238216 kB

NFS_Unstable: 0 kB

Bounce: 0 kB

WritebackTmp: 0 kB

CommitLimit: 89421740 kB

Committed_AS: 7028572 kB

VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB

VmallocUsed: 518656 kB

VmallocChunk: 34358945788 kB

HardwareCorrupted: 0 kB

AnonHugePages: 1648640 kB

CmaTotal: 16384 kB

CmaFree: 10532 kB

HugePages_Total: 10116

HugePages_Free: 515

HugePages_Rsvd: 0

HugePages_Surp: 0

Hugepagesize: 2048 kB

DirectMap4k: 601952 kB

DirectMap2M: 21059584 kB

DirectMap1G: 45088768 kB

**huge page function disable**

[*@* ~]$ free -g

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
```

Mem:             62          34           1          21          25          32

Swap:            63           0          63

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Or maybe [dba.se]  . Good luck.